# Android icon showing when turning Wi-Fi on

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notification-icons

Sometimes when I turn Wi-Fi or internet data on, an icon appears at the notification bar of my android 6.0 device that looks like the android bot surrounded by 2 circling arrows like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XHIjJf6P9NT3XchF61CSd4Ifewuaha6g2sC98cxsEZmXBaehp2_XA47kjzXjNWK-fQ=w300) (it is not exactly like this. The icon I am seeing is white and the arrows are thinner but the concept is very similar) and lasts for a few seconds. What does that mean? Is Android updating and if yes, what kind of updates is it getting?

*By the way, I have auto update and sync turned off. That's why I wonder what kind of updates these are.

My device is an LG G4

Comment: please mention your device name

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168621/what-is-this-cyanogenmod-13-icon-symbolising?rq=1

Comment: @RahulGopi Edited my question to include it

Comment: @RahulGopi That is not the icon that I am describing. Just found a picture of it and I am updating my question.

Comment: Do you have sync turned on? This should be the sync icon

Comment: Left or right side? Left is an app, right is a system icon.

Comment: @esQmo Sync is OFF

Comment: @acejavelin it is on the left side

Comment: Check in Settings->Accounts, and check whether there is any tick mark in `Auto-sync data`. If yes, sync activated. If No, sync is not activated, maybe any other issue.

Comment: @RahulGopi Nope...auto sync is off...

Comment: Icons in the left side are for non-system apps. Thus this icon may belong to an app that you installed. And since android 5, the system force all icons to be in white, even though some devices don't respect this rule.

Comment: @esQmo I don't think I have any app that would create such an icon. In addition if I go and see my data usage I can see that 1,4 megabytes were used by the 'android operating system'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an LG phone aswell (not the G4) and icon that you are described is probably icon which shows up when phone is checking for updates of android or updates for LG apps. You can probably change when it will check for updates. I don't have any sources about this but I know that  because I catch notification several times when on slow cellular data.
Edit here is the photo of icon I get when checking for updates:
[image]

Also here is "app updater" app icon it's very similar to picture you posted 
[image]

Comment: Yes that is exactly the icon!